# How to develop iphone app with database?

Tags: iphone, ipad, applet

I want to develop a CRM iphone app. I think there are 2 methods to deal with the data store, one is using the Sqlite(but it can not share datas with others ?), the other method is using the webservice(let the app CURD data by one web application), I want to know which is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question is not about having one or the other, you could have both: Webservices to expose a central server somewhere where common data is stored and your local SQLite database where a copy of this data is stored. This allows you for fast search etc. instead of contacting some remote server that may or may not be on-line.

Comment: Yes, a local data store will be immensely useful especially for the times when network access isn't available. +1

Comment: I care the data is too large to store in local

Comment: Could you tell me is it general to setup a central server to support the database-base app ? i think SQLite is enough good if do not need to share the data.

Comment: @sharp, yes its quite common to have a central database that everybody accesses using web services.

Comment: @sharp, you can store large amounts on the phone as long as its not all needed at the same time in the internal memory. the problem that you have when storing locally is synchronization.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like it's a little complex to create a CRM for Iphone :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share your data then you have to store your data in webdatabase otherwise store in sqlite

you can store your data in sqlite for fast access and when you want to share that time you can send it to webservice and retrive when you need to see more data